# How can I prevent the glm() function from adding back-ticks to some of my variable names?

Tags: r, data.table, glm

I'm using glm() to create some models. The variables in my input data.table have names like "day" and "day^2". The model generated by glm() puts back-ticks around any variable with a polynomial term, which throttles various components of my downstream workflow.

```
library(data.table)

# Generate some sample data
covariates <- data.table('day' = 1:10,
                         'day^2' = (1:10)^2)
theta <- sample(x = 0:1, size = 10, replace = TRUE)

# Produce a model from glm()
mod <- glm(formula = theta ~ .,
           data = covariates,
           family = 'binomial')
```

I want to be able to check the model coefficients and see "day" and "day^2", but instead I'm seeing "day" and "`day^2`":

```
# Check the coefficient names output from glm()
names(mod$coefficients)
# [1] "(Intercept)" "day"         "`day^2`"   

# Check the colnames(covariates) to verify we did not put in back-ticks
colnames(covariates)
# [1] "day"   "day^2"

# Eliminate the "(Intercept)" term from mods names,
# then compare the outcome to the colnames of covariates
# to verify that we are not imagining the back-ticks
names(mod$coefficients[-1]) == colnames(covariates)
# [1]  TRUE FALSE
```

Am I out of luck? Is glm() just not going to respect my polynomial variable names?

EDITED TO ADD: 
Well, data.table is so fully entrenched in my workflow that I didn't even consider trying this out with a data.frame, but it just occurred to me. Here is what happens with data.frames:

```
# Generate some sample data using a traditional data.frame instead of data.table
covariates <- data.frame('day' = 1:10,
                         'day^2' = (1:10)^2)

# Check the column names; data.frame coerces '^' to '.': 
colnames(covariates)
# [1] "day"   "day.2"
```

Thus, perhaps the issue is with data.table not being watertight compatible with glm() in this case, given that data.table allows much more flexibility with my polynomial variable names, which data.frame would have coerced to '.' (and which glm ultimately ends up coercing by adding back-ticks!).

Comment: It's doing the best it can given that you're insisting on not using syntactically valid names. ;) The `^` character makes the column name "non-standard" and R will have to use backticks to avoid altering the name even more dramatically. See, eg, `make.names("day^2")`.

Comment: Another way to think about this is that `glm()` **is** respecting your non-standard column names. The way R preserves names that aren't syntactically valid is by enclosing them in back ticks. You can, eg, force `data.frame()` to use a non-standard column name by putting it in back ticks.

Comment: @joran, you're absolutely right. Just edited my answer to add a few more insights. Seems like a worthwhile caveat against taking full advantage of how permissive data.table is with respect to column names.

Comment: both `data.table` and the tidyverse in general are more permissive by default about non-syntactic names than base R is (see the `check.names=` argument to `read.table()`); this issue is coming up more and more often as use of data.table and tidyverse becomes more common ...